# jquery scroll effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FmNQq/

I would like to add a scroll effect with jquery, but dont really know how?
Can you help me amend my code?

Comment: -1. Tell us what kind of effect you are looking for. ALSO, you haven't tried anything at all!

Comment: I have tried adding a scroll effect, does it now show in the jsfiddle?

Comment: @PD24, in the jsFiddle you provided.. There is no jQuery. _This_ is what you need to make the scroll effect happen. Try some first, the if it doesn't work, ask :)

Comment: maybe a slide is better than scroll?

Comment: There is no JavaScript in your jsFiddle... heck, jQuery is not even selected.  So you want us to write all your code for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done directly with `.hover` where the handler is called when the mouse enters or leaves the element, and `.slideDown`/`.slideUp` to animate: http://jsfiddle.net/FmNQq/4/.

```
$(".sub_nav, .sub_nav2").hover(function() {

    // toggle child <ul> with a slide animation
    // when mouse enters or leaves

    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Im a visual learner so needed to see how things were working. I really really appreciate the help. Shame i get bullied with down votes.